# print values using python 3.4.3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i am using python script to get browser height using selenium webdriver chrome..

`print(browser.get_window_size())`

which prints me: `{'width': 1382, 'height': 744}`

i would like to get only height from above..so for getting it i wrote below code:

`data = browser.get_window_size();`
`print(data.height);`

but i am getting error:

`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'height'`

i am new to python, please help or suggest some other way.. thanks in advance..

Comment: `print(data['height'])`? [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) are pretty central to Python, so if you don't know how to use them you'll have a tricky time of it...

Comment: thanks a lot @jonrsharpe sir.. works perfect... for me.. thanks you save my time...and thanks too for the Dictionaries link... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do

```
print(data['height'])
```

please note, that you say you want to print width but in your example you are printing height, maybe you need

```
print(data['width'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary's elements are accessed with the `[]` operator:

```
print(data['height'])
```